Blow-up of a secant variety and its exceptional divisor
Let $X \subseteq \mathbb P^n$ be a smooth projectively normal variety. Let $Y := \mathrm{Sec}_1(X)$ be the (first) secant variety of $X$, i.e. the Zariski closure of the union of all lines in $\mathbb P^n$ spanned by two different points on $X$. The secant variety $Y$ is singular only along $X$, and intuitively, the transverse section of $Y$ at a singular point $x \in X$ should look like an ordinary double point. (I have in mind the examples like $X = \nu_4(\mathbb P^1) \subseteq \mathbb P^4$ or  $X = \nu_2(\mathbb P^2) \subseteq \mathbb P^5$.) Consider the blow-up $\pi\,\colon\ \operatorname{Bl}_XY \to Y$ of $Y$ along $X$.
Is it true that (1) if $X$ is smooth then $\operatorname{Bl}_XY$ is also smooth, and (2) the exceptional divisor $E$ is a fibration in quadrics over $X$? What happens when $X$ is replaced by e.g. $\operatorname{Cone}(X)$? I am looking for a more geometric description.

The fiber of $E \to X$ over a point $x \in X$ is the projection of $X$ from the tangent space at $x$. In your two examples it is, indeed, a smooth conic, but in general it is more complicated.
